# Radio button in LWC design attributes

Tags: lightning-web-components, design-attributes

I have a LWC which takes two boolean inputs `isVideo` and `isImage` in JavaScript file. Based on the value of `isVideo` or `isImage`, the LWC behaves differently. At a time only one has to be true. While inserting the component on lightning detail page using Lightning App Builder, I want to have a radio button to select `isVideo` or `isImage`. I wish to use design attributes to achieve it. This means that the same component gets added twice but with true for `isVideo` the first time and true for `isImage` the second time. I referred [this site](https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/04/how-to-design-attributes-in-lightning.html) and [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags). Is there a way to add a radio button in design attributes? Please guide. Thank You!

**meta.xml file**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>   
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="isVideo" type="Boolean" label="Video Component"/>
            <property name="isVideo" type="Boolean" label="Image Component"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify a list of options, you need to do so in a single attribute. such as:

```
<targetConfig targets="...">
  <property datasource="Video,Image" name="mediaType" type="String" required="true" />
  ...
</targetConfig>
```

And in your JS file:

```
isVideo;
isImage;
@api set mediaType(value) {
  this.isVideo = value === 'Video';
  this.isImage = value === 'Audio';
}
get mediaType() {
  return this.isVideo? 'Video': this.isAudio? 'Audio': '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am getting the error `The 'mediaType' property doesn't exist on the component.` What is wrong here?

Comment: @Koustubh I forgot it should have been marked with the api decorator: `import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc'; ... @api set mediaType(value) { ... }` Also, just tested, a setter is required. See edits.